# Flutter manage push and pop for persistent bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm using Custom Tab navigator to manage persistent bottom navigation bar across all the screens.
Due this Tab navigator sits in one StatefulWidget to host the tabs in the app, So unable to pop to the other widget out of these tabs and hosted widget.

Ex : After successful login, There is one widget Dashboard and it hosts the bottom navigation and tabs using Navigator. Now i want to logout from one of the tab and should navigate to the login screen, which is not part of any tabs or hosted widget.

While trying to push to Login widget, Showing only the blank screen. Because no route within the Custom navigator.

Any solution for this without using any package for persistent bottom navigation.

Comment: `persistent bottom navigation` has many bug, could you find any package like with that?